# how to run a script to get feedback from user after service done?

Tags: php, event-handling, cron

Suppose a user has booked an appointment for a service. Once service is done, I want to run a php script so that i can get user feedback whenever he/she is coming on that website. It is done in many websites like ola, paytm etc...

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Where is your code?

Comment: We need much more Infos, Code, Links, Examples ...

Comment: first of all im trying to run php file with other php file having crontab command in it. but its not working

Comment: <?php

$path = dirname(__FILE__);
$cron = $path . "/get_feedback.php";
echo exec("***** php -q ".$cron." &> /dev/null");

?>

Answer (score 0):

you can set a value in the users table like booked_services or something, and set it to the number of the services booked..

and in the place you want to send the notification, let's say home page.. set the condition .. if the number is not 0 -> send the notification

something like..

`if($num_services > 0){
  doNotification();
}`

Comment: but i want to send the notification once service is done not just after booking of service?

Comment: same code applies, just add it where the "service is done" exists

Comment: I know only time when service will be done. but i dont know how to run a file on that time?

Comment: after executing the "success" thing, call the file